# Erro Unsupported projection option: $project "code":2,"codeName":"BadValue"

Tags: mongodb

Gostaria de fazer uma busca onde quero somente os registros onde `watson` for igual a `true` e `node-visited` for igual a `Bem-vindo`

[image: Documento no Mongo]

Estava fazendo desta forma

```
db.getCollection('conversations').find({'watson':true},
{    
$project: 
{
    messages: 
    {
        $filter: 
        {  
            input: '$messages',
              as: 'message',
            cond: 
            {
                $eq:['$$message.output.nodes_visited','Bem-vindo']
            } 
        }
    }
}
})
```

Mas não funcionou e deu o seguinte erro

```
Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: $project: { messages: { $filter: { input: \"$messages\", as: \"message\", cond: { $eq: [ \"$$message.output.nodes_visited\", undefined ] } } } }",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Comment: Identifiquei o erro, o $filter só funciona com aggregate `db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate({$match:'watson':true},`, mas ainda nao esta filtrando certo

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei o erro, o $filter só funciona com aggregate `db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate({$match:'watson':true}`, mas ainda nao esta filtrando certo